# Why is the same Wordpress index.html URL different on desktop and Android browsers?

Tags: wordpress

I uploaded a new responsive web design index.html page to my Wordpress account root folder www. When I click on the link in the desktop, it correctly displays the URL and visits the page. But on my Chrome browser in my Android device, tapping on the same link keeps the page the same, but shows a modified URL.

Instead of http://www.sitename.com/folder1/categoryfolder2/folder3/, the mobile phone shows http://www.sitename.com/folder1/**#** categoryfolder2/folder3/ **8** (bold text to highlight the changes).

The links are image buttons linking to the category URLs of the site that are lined up at right. The page displays correctly in either case. How or why does my Android browser change the URL? A Bluehost tech said the issue was not from their end.

Here is my htaccess file in "folder1." If I change any of the lines, pages on the desktop go to 404 error:

```
#BEGIN WordPress 

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 

RewriteEngine On RewriteBase /folder1/ 

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /folder1/index.php [L] 

</IfModule>

#END WordPress
```

I realize that I need to say that the www/index.html is not part of Wordpress. The links go to a Wordpress blog on the same site, all in /folder1.

Comment: Please check there is modification in .htaccess file.Its better to rename and regenerate it for accurate result.If you are using AMP please disable and check.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this should be asked on the stackexchange dedicated to Wordpress: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I've only skimmed through the question, but to me, it's very illogical to have a *responsive* website and serve different URL according to screen size. That is not responsive.

Comment: The responsive index.html fits mobile and desktop with equal ease. Evidently the post was not clear. There is only one set of responsive URLs. The image links merely resize to fit the screen. There are no media queries for different screens. Hope this clarifies things.

Comment: @Rob I posted it there. Thanks. No answer there either. A confounding issue!